# Have there been gay riots in the US?

Tags: united-states

I was wondering has there ever been uprisings in the history of the US that were for gay rights or started by gay people?

Comment: [Stonewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonewall_riots#Police_raid) wouldn't fit the narrow definition of this question "started by gays". I feel this question is actually two questions, one that asks for a list and one that asks for an assessment of culpability.

Answer (score 11):

Yes - the most famous of these is the [Stonewall Riots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonewall_riots), in NYC in 1969. But there is actually a [long history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pre-Stonewall_LGBT_actions_in_the_United_States) of direct action in support of gay rights predating Stonewall, some of them violent.

Answer (score 4):

For your question about uprisings in history that were related to gay rights and occurred in the United States   I did some initial research. However to fully answer your question a little more information is required as to what you meant by uprising and if you were looking for a particular time frame in US history?

I think that these websites can help you.
http://topics.nytimes.com/topics/reference/timestopics/subjects/s/stonewall_rebellion/index.html
http://www.huffingtonpost.com/news/stonewall-riots-anniversary

To answer your initial question yes there have been riots in the history of the United States that have been a direct result of issues pertaining to the gay community. The articles above describe one of the most famous riots known the Stonewall Rebellion which took place on June 27th, 1969. Police officers became involved in a fight at the Stonewall Inn which was a well known hangout for gay, lesbian and transgender patrons. 
The article describing the Stonewall Rebellion comes from the New York Times which can be considered a very reliable source considering the paper has won over a 100 Pulitzer prize awards additionally with the Stonewall Riots having taken place in New York the New York Times is a great source of information pertaining to this topic. 
The second article comes from another credible source the Huffington Post which happened to be covering the 40th anniversary of the Stonewall Riots.
Now in case you would like to do further research into the Stonewall Rebellion or perhaps other gay 
rights movements let me describe how I found this site:

1) I started with the search engine Google.

2) I typed in “gay rights riot and united states” into the search box (you don't need to use the “ ” marks).
The first result was for Huffington Post article to the Stonewall Riots anniversary article. To determine if the Huffington Post was giving accurate information I typed into google “Stonewall and New York Times) which brought me to my second article.

I hope that these articles can help you.  If you need more help, in finding other sources on Stonewall or similar events in history please feel free to respond again.

Comment: Just as we don't use salutations here, your name bullet at the end will do for a signature. Also, this probably isn't the place for a lesson in how to use Google to research things, so you may consider editing that part out of your answer yourself. Other than that, a very good effort for a first post. +1 from me.

Comment: more details about the riots themselves and less about how the times and huffington post are great sources and how to find them would make this a much better answer

Comment: -1 for "another credible source the Huffington Post". Or NYT for that matter. You may wish to Google "Duranty" to see how they get their Pulitzers

Comment: +1 because DVK is making some ridiculous point about communism in the 20s. The fact is the NYT is quite good for a popular (non-scholarly) source. However, the NYT has got nothing on wikipedia, [go there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stonewall_riots). It's a well cited article. Also I agree with T.E.D.